# Vista 32 bit to Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit on AMD processor?

Tags: windows, installation

I am upgrading Vista 32 bit to Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit on AMD processor. 
When I put DVD Windows 7 it does not boot from it....
Dvd ok as can see other CD files.
Boot work ok as I can boot from Acronics CD.
Tested same W7 DVD and it work ok in my laptop and it start installation.
Do I need to make any change in BIOS or why this Windows DVD don't work?

Additions:
AMD processor is 64 bit for sure. I can see in BIOS it shows 64 bit. When I tested DVD on my laptop which is 32 bit at least Windows7 installation start. On this computer even installation don't start.

Comment: What is your processor?  Maybe it doesn't support 64-bit.  Please use CPU-Z and tell us what processor it reports.  http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: AMD processor is 64 bit for sure. I can see in BIOS it shows 64 bit. When I tested DVD on my laptop which is 32 bit at least Windows installation start. On this computer even installation don't start.

Comment: Instead of the nearly incomprehensible "When I put DVD Windows 7 it does not boot from it", please describe your machine's behaviour **accurately**; **in detail** with the exact messages, lights, beeps, and whatnot; and **in comprehensible English**.  This is not least because your machine will be **telling you** why it is not bootstrapping.

Comment: When I try to boot from DVD by using Windows 7 DVD, it first gives option of F2 for setup and F12 for boot sequence. If I select F12 and select option - boot from DVD/CD, it reads DVD and shows black page with cursor on top left side. It keeps blinking and nothing happen. If I don't select any option F2/F12, then it ends up on same black page with blinking cursor to top left side.

Comment: Initially there were two HDs connecting with SATA0 and SATA2 and DVD was on SATA3. Now I removed 2nd HD and HD 1 is connected with SATA0 and DVD with SATA1. Installed Vista is 32 bit and Windows 7 DVD is 64 bit. Just wonder if there any change required in BIOS for this installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootable USB was solution here.....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DVD drive is set as the bootdisk.

When you say it does not boot, it sounds like BIOS is choosing the HD first.

You should also post your motherboard. We can dig up the user manual.

Comment: Yes, DVD is set as bootdisk and first in order.

Comment: It does not boot from DVD means that system don't start Windows7 installation. Processor is AMD Athlon(tm) 64x2 Dual Core Precessor 4000+  Motherboard>> Manufacturer: Dell >Product: 0RY206 >Chipset: nVidia MCP61

Comment: Odd, I'd burn another DVD.  There is just no other way around it. The DVD drive is fine, the motherboard OK, BIOS OK.  Try burning another DVD or use a USB drive.

Comment: I just made USB bootable from that DVD and tried but no luck. In USB, software created two files .IMA and .BIN

Comment: To make a bootable USB, you should follow the steps here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2011/09/14/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-8-developer-preview.aspx. They will work for Vista/7/8.

Comment: I just noticed another point. When I browse DVD W7 in my laptop (WXP) I do see 6 folders and 4 files. While when I browse same DVD in Vista I do see a file with .iso image. That this mean?

Comment: That this mean? = What this mean?

Comment: I have no *.iso file on my W7 DVD. . . I still think you should reburn the DVD.

Comment: OK, it worked with USB. On making usb bootable with W7 files, it started installation. Still don't know what was wrong with this DVD and this system. This DVD works ok on other systems.